# Finding all properties that are the same generic class

Tags: c#, generics

If you're unfamiliar with the Entity Framework, it generates a class that looks like

```
public partial class contextontext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<foo> foo { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<bar> bar { get; set; }
    //Etc, there could be lots of these DbSet properties
}
```

I'm trying to build a list of types that there are `DbSet<T>` collections for, but I'm not sure how to check for a generic type. I got it to work using `` PropertyType.ToString().StartsWith("System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1") `` but that seems like a messy and unnecessarily complicated way to do it. This is the full LINQ I use to get the properties.

```
foreach (var property in context.GetType().GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).Where(p => p.PropertyType.ToString().StartsWith("System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1")))
{
   Type type = property.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0];

   //other stuff...
}
```

I poked around in the property object, but didn't find any leads. There's a `Type` in there, but that's always the type specific implementation of the generic DbSet (as it should be). How would I check to see if it's the generic collection, regardless of what type it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want simply:

```
var propertyType = property.PropertyType;

if (propertyType.IsGenericType
  && propertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DbSet<>))
{
  // ...
}
```

I see now your `Where` far to the right in your code. That would be:

```
.Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType
  && p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DbSet<>))
```

The [method `GetGenericTypeDefinition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition.aspx) goes from the concrete constructed ("closed") generic type (e.g. `DbSet<foo>`), to the definition of the type (here `DbSet<TEntity>`).